# Can someone explain the meaning of this scanf code

Tags: c, input, compiler-construction, scanf

I am trying to understand this code for calculating first and follow sets of a grammar. 
In this `scanf` has been used with multiple inputs

`scanf("%s%c",a[i],&ch);`

where `a` is 2D array and `ch` is a char. Can someone explain the meaning of this line?

Comment: No problem, this reference tells you all about it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: You are not paying anyone on SO to answer your question urgently, people here answers with their free time and not based on your need.

Comment: After a successful call to `scanf()` as shown (return value 2), `a[i]` will contain a string with no white space in it and `ch` will contain a white space character.  You may have suffered a buffer overflow since you didn't limit the size of the string read into `a[i]`; you won't know about that until things start going wrong, though, and that'll usually be a long way away from where the trouble is.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler Thanks a lot man. This really helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in remarks `scanf("%s%c",a[i],&ch);` try to read a 'word' as a string in `a[i]` and a char in *ch*

Because a 'word' is ended by a separator and there is no space between *%s* and *%c* if a character is read to set *ch* that character is the first separator

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char s[10], ch;
  printf("%d\n", scanf("%s%c", s, &ch));
  printf("'%s' '%c' (%d)\n", s, ch, ch);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze q
2
'aze' ' ' (32)
```

so *ch* does not get *q* but the first space after "aze"

Of course in the case of *aze*<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze
2
'aze' '
' (10)
```

*ch* get *newline*

---

The proper way to not take the risk to write out of the string is to set the max number of characters, in my example above `scanf("%9s%c", s, &ch)` (9 rather than 10 to have the place for the null character ending the string)

If the available 'word' has at least 10 characters the 10nth will be get by *ch* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1234567890
2
'123456789' '0' (48)
```

---

Adding a space between *%s* and *%c* changes the behavior because the separators are skip between the 'word' and the returned character, example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char s[10], ch;
  printf("%d\n", scanf("%9s %c", s, &ch));
  printf("'%s' '%c' (%d)\n", s, ch, ch);
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze    q
2
'aze' 'q' (113)
```

so that time *ch* gets *q*